# Kubernetes cannot start container due to AppArmor problems

Tags: kubernetes, apparmor, rke2

I'm running an RKE2 cluster with 1 master node and 3 worker nodes. I'm trying to deploy my own custom application on it. It consists of two parts: a Memcache container, which runs fine, and a PHP-FPM container which won't start. The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: open /proc/self/attr/exec: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I do not understand why this is happening, since the memcache container is starting up just fine.

I've tried disabling and/or removing AppArmor, but RKE2 does not like that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall apparmor again, then restart docker.

> AppArmor security profiles for Docker
>
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/